# F# trying to create a better printf

Tags: f#, unit-type

I'm trying to create a print statement that can print any type. I want to use type pattern matching to achieve this.

This doesn't work:

```
let print x = match x with | :? int -> printf "INT"; | _ -> None;;
```

I get the message:

> let print x = match x with | :? int -> printf "INT"; | _ -> None;;
>   -----------------------------^^^^^^
>
> stdin(47,30): error FS0008: This runtime coercion or type test from
>   type
>       'a  to
>       int involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point.  Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types.
>   Further type annotations are needed.

So, i can't do type matching on an int? What other types can i not do type matching on? What does it mean that further type annotations are needed?

Comment: It means it can't infer the type of "x" from the code you've given it so far.  Pad's answer should be the fix.  That or you could just do a "%A" as the mask for printing.

Comment: Just to make @Onorio's comment more explicit: the function you are trying to create already exists: `printfn "%A" x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type test is performed on reference types only. Therefore:

```
let print x = 
    match box x with 
    | :? int -> printf "INT"
    | _ -> ()
```

or

```
let print (x: obj) = 
    match x with 
    | :? int -> printf "INT"
    | _ -> ()
```

would work.

Notice that your function doesn't type check since `None` is of `option` type which is different from `unit` type of `printf "INT"`.